# Custom Post Type meta box Radio-button(s) output

Tags: php, css, wordpress, meta-boxes

I like to do a simple thing with my custom meta box, but i d'ont find a (easy) solution for this problem.

I have done a custom post type with some meta boxes => text, textarea, select fields, ect.

all work just fine. Now if i set the button to sold,(see code excerpt from the radio array below) the text(div) should be red; if i set it to for_sale, it should be green.

but i have no idea how to do this, i mean there are this two states possible. nothing else.
and that is what i want.
**but the html output is only text**. or text in a html-tag, this i can style with css, but it would be red, or it is blue, green what else i sett it. 
is there a simple thing, like a class to set for each value? i c'ant find an answer. i hope i have explained it understandable. thanks so much for taking time for this.

```
array(
'label' => 'Status',
'desc'  => 'product status',
'id'    => $prefix.'radio_status',
'type'  => 'radio',
'options' => array (
    'one' => array (
        'label' => 'Product for sale',
        'value' => 'for_sale'
    ),
    'two' => array (
        'label' => 'Product is sold',
        'value' => 'is_sold'
    ),
),
),
```

EDIT :)

```
<span class="saleBox"><span class="noBox"><?php echo $post_meta_data['custom_radio_status'][0]; ?></span></span>
```

Thats the HTML, and what i get is the value thats setted.

```
<span class="saleBox"><span class="noBox">for sale</span></span>
```

or then: *soled

So i need a Output with a true-value, or class, ID,... something that i can adress with css.

---

A good idea that works. only thing that i doesen't understand is, is must call the array.

```
<?php $post_meta_data = get_post_custom($post->ID); ?>
```

if i call only the specific data:

```
<?php get_post_meta($post->ID, 'custom_radio_status', true) ?>
```

for me, it won't. or i made a typo. it doesen't matter i works!

thank you mr. Maguire

Comment: Show your html output for this radio buttons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a conditional statement, something like:

```
<span class = "
<?php
    if ($post_meta_data['custom_radio_status'][0] == "is_sold"){
        echo "red_class";
     }else{
        echo "green_class";
    }
?>
">
```